# Configuring routing for two networks (one internal, one external)

Tags: networking, dns, routing

Here's the situation.  My Mac connects to two networks - one internal, one external.  The internal DNS works for both internal and external URLs, the external DNS (obviously) knows nothing about the internal URLs.  The internal network does not connect to external IPs, the external network does not connect to internal IPs.

So depending on how I set up the Service Order in the Network section of the System Preferences:

So if I put the internal network before the external in the service order:

1. Internal DNS answers all requests correctly (for both internal and external URLs)
2. Internal network cannot connect to external URLs, so I guess I need to add a bunch of entries to the routing table so that every thing that isn't an internal IP gets sent to the external network.

If I put the external network first and the internal network second, and add an entry to the routing table so that all internal requests go to the internal network:

1. Even if I add the internal DNS first in the setup of the external network, I still can't resolve internal URLs.

So here are my questions:

1) Why can't I resolve internal URLs?  Since I've got the entry in the routing table, sending all internal IPs to the internal network, shouldn't DNS requests go to the internal DNS, even though the external network is first in the service order?

2) Is there a clever way to add entries to the routing table to say "everything except 10.x.x.x goes to network X"?

p.s. For my question #2, I was thinking that the way to specify "everything except 10.x.x.x" was to have a whole series of route commands:

```
/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 -netmask 128.0.0.0 -interface en0
/sbin/route add -net  64.0.0.0 -netmask 192.0.0.0 -interface en0
/sbin/route add -net  32.0.0.0 -netmask 224.0.0.0 -interface en0
/sbin/route add -net  16.0.0.0 -netmask 240.0.0.0 -interface en0
```

but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Comment: Is the internal network really a network with subnets and routing of just a big LAN?

Comment: Also, are you connected to the internal and external through two interfaces?

Comment: Two interfaces - one wired, one wireless.  The internal network (10.x.x.x) is huge and geographically distributed (not just a LAN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your internal network is like 10.0.0.0/8 with gateway 10.0.0.1 on eth1 and your external default gateway is on eth1 with IP a.b.c.d, this should do it:

`route change default -interface en0
route add -net 10.0.0.0 -netmask 255.0.0.0 -interface en1`

you can also setup these in your network scripts (you can do it in Linux - not sure about Mac), see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-route-add/) as an example. This actually would be a more persistent way since you do not have to add there routes manually at every boot (or put them in a script).

Update: commands updated for Mac OS X as per OPs comment, see the link for Linux alternatives.

Comment: I think this works, but your answer uses the Linux format, I'm on a Mac.  I think the equivalent commands (darn this mini-markdown formatting) are [route change default -interface en0] and [route add -net 10.0.0.0 -netmask 255.0.0.0 -interface en1], I think it picked the correct gateways for each interface.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I missed that part.

Comment: @Mahdi - You should considering updating the answer in that case.

Comment: I am, i just need to get to a PC. :)